# Botón de ver más en Laravel

Tags: laravel, ajax

he estado intentando realizar un botón de ver más, lo que quiero hacer con laravel 5.7 y ajax, hasta ahora no lo he logrado, investigue y lo máximo que pude lograr es lo siguiente:

El html

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(".clickMe").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type:'GET',
        url: "{{ url('loadMore/4') }}",
      }).done(function(data){
        var len=data.length;
        console.log(len);
         //Perform ANy action after successfuly post data
         var rows = '';
        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
              rows += data[i].titulo;
        } 

        $("#morePosts").html(rows);  
      })  

  });
</script>
```

el controlador

```
public function loadMore($numRecibido){

 $post = Publicacion::take(1)->skip($numRecibido)->get();
 return response()->json($post);
}
```

Agradecería si me pueden ayudar

Comment: que te devuelve el controlador, cada vez que presionas el boton? siempre los mismos registros?

Comment: Exacto, solo me devuelve un mismo registro

Comment: Le estás enviando siempre el mismo parámetro en la URL ...

Comment: @Shaz si, solo para prueba . Aunque voy cambiando manualmente pero aun así solo retorna un único registro.

Comment: ¿para qué utilizas get() si solo vas a obtener un registro?

Comment: pues en realidad, debería devolver varios registros, ya los quiero limitar a unos cuantos `SELECT * FROM publicacione LIMIT 0 , 3` ese es el código de sql que quiero repetir

Comment: agregue una respuesta con algunas opciones, espero pueda ayudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el código que compartes, le indicas como parámetro a tu url `loadMore/4`.
Donde 4 será el valor de tu `offset` para tu consulta y el `limit` siempre será 1, según lo que indicas en el controlador.

Teniendo eso en cuenta, si tienes la siguiente tabla en tu base de datos

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Heading 1      |     Heading 2    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         4        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          5          |         5        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

con el código compartido siempre te traería el registro 5.

Entonces, lo que te recomiendo en este caso, si es que quieres traer de n registros por cada vez que presionas el botón, es enviar en el parámetro, donde actualmente tienes un 4, la cantidad de registros que llevas mostrando en el front.

Al principio cargarías 2, entonces en la url marcas `loadMore/2`, el controlador te retornará 1 registros y lo agregas al listado que tienes en el front y el valor de tu url ahora sería `loadMore/3`, claramente este numero debe ser parametrizable de tu función de javascript.

```
$(".clickMe").click(function(e){
      var cantidadRegistros = $(this).data('cantidad'); // suponiendo que la cantidad la vas a estar almacenando en un atributo data-cantidad
      $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type:'GET',
        url: "{{ url('loadMore/"+cantidadRegistros+"') }}",
      }).done(function(data){
        var len=data.length;
        console.log(len);
         //Perform ANy action after successfuly post data
         var rows = '';
        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
              rows += data[i].titulo;
        } 

        $("#morePosts").html(rows);  
      })  

  });
```

Ahora si lo que buscas es traer los mismos registros ya cargados, pero algunos registros mas tendrías que cambiar la lógica del controlador

```
$post = Publicacion::take($numRecibido)->get();
```

Donde `$numRecibido` será el valor del `LIMIT` de tu consulta, el cual deberia ser mayor que la consulta anterior, osea que si te trajiste 4 registros la primera vez, la segunda en vez de 4 le pongas 8 y así...

[Documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Comment: Gracias me funciono